# How to use the Asuran Outsourcing guild upgrade?

Tags: guild-wars-2

So there is a guild upgrade to allow you to build something without using a slot. We have it available, but I can't figure out how to use it?

Can someone tell me how we can make use of it? Clicking 'Activate' does nothing.
[image]

Ref: http://wiki.guildwars2.com/wiki/Influence#Politics

Comment: I don't know myself, but this [comment](http://www.gw2db.com/guildupgrades/40-contract-asuran-outsourcing) says it automatically starts the next upgrade in the queue?

Comment: Ah, so we need to queue up 3 items and then activate it. I'll give this a try once we have some more inf to spend :)

Comment: Given that you did all the actual legwork in confirming it, you should answer your own question :P

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order to use the `Contract Asuran Outsourcing` first your guild will need to achieve level 3 in [Politics](http://wiki.guildwars2.com/wiki/Politics#Politics).
Then you can build this upgrade, which is a consumable item for 200 influence.
Then queue up 2 or 3 items, depending on if you have `Guild Workshop` or not. Then when you click this item it will start the first queued item *not currently in progress*.